# Saving F# types to a database

Tags: entity-framework, f#, domain-driven-design

A [lot](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2013/02/17/domain-driven-design-with-fsharp-and-eventstore/) of f# articles [recommend](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/no-uml-diagrams/) using fsharp's built in types such as discriminated unions, tuples and records to model the domain. Once we have this model, how can it be persisted to a database?

Entity framework and type providers only work with standard classes with mutable properties.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can put the `[<CLIMutable>]` attribute on records:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Foo = { Bar : string; Baz : int }
```

This will turn it into a class with mutable properties, *when viewed through IL, or from C# or Visual Basic*. Viewed from F#, it still looks like an immutable record.

This doesn't really address the problem, though, because there's no corresponding feature for (de)serialising Discriminated Unions.

(As a side remark, IIRC, JSON.net has support for both F# records and discriminated unions, but so far, that's the only exception I'm aware of.)

In my opinion, this is a **blessing in disguise**, because **a Domain Model should be decoupled from persistence details**.

In C#, you may *think* that an ORM like Entity Framework provides such decoupling, but it doesn't. Even with so-called code-first POCO Entities, you still end up creating a *relational* model, instead of an object-oriented model. Just think of 'navigation properties', which are purely relational concerns. In OOD, such properties violate the [law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (we call them *Train Wrecks*).

If you want to keep a Domain Model decoupled from implementation details, you'll need to create the model first, and then figure out a way to persist it afterwards. How you do that depends on the persistence technology used.

Comment: +1000 "this is a blessing in disguise, because a Domain Model should be decoupled from persistence details.".

Comment: @mark-seeman If the domain and persistence objects are separate, won't that result in a whole load of mapping code mapping one to the other when saving/retrieving data from the database?

Comment: @Kurren Only if you use 'objects' for persistence ;)

Comment: There is no way to decouple a domain model from persistence details. The domain model may be able to hide the details from its users though. In fact I believe you should not try too hard to hide this “detail”. There are libraries available now that allow you to test your persistence details (queries for example) without the need for much mocking (see Effort.EF6 for example). It means you can embrace your persistence details even when doing TDD and the notion of trying to hide them seems outdated (IMO).

Comment: @Kurren "whole load of mapping code mapping one to the other when saving/retrieving data" is a small price compared to horrors of dealing with domain models dictated by db schema. It's sad that EF and other ORMs try to pretend otherwise. Single Responsibility principle ftw

Comment: @MarkSeemann could you please elaborate on your "only if you use objects for persistence" comment? As far as I am concerned, I am worried about forgetting to update DTOs when I add properties to domain entities, so I am wondering if there exists a compile-time F# feature similar to pattern matching that could help with that

Comment: @tobiak777 I'd love to, but that requires more explanation than fits here. I've on my backlog to answer a question on my blog, so you may want to watch that space: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2023/07/17/works-on-most-machines#2adbe12cf0e541e7b76cf39037c6a96c