# F# mapping data entities to domain entities; what is meant by "using objects for persistance"?

Tags: mongodb, f#, mapping, persistence

In my spare time, I'm trying restart my effort to learn F#. I'm doing so by trying to create a simple application that will allow me to analyze my financial transactions. 
My first attempt at creating this application failed due to the persistence step. I used SQL and the EntityFramework package, but the latter generated database entities, which I did not want to use throughout my application since they're all mutable (I think..). Instead I had to map these database entities to domain entities. Much manual glue code later it worked....until I found a bug and was forced to replace much of that glue code. That was the tipping point that made me quit.

On SO I found a question describing my situation, e.g. [Saving F# types to a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892254/saving-f-types-to-a-database). Mark Seeman suggested that the pain of mapping can be overcome if I'd not use objects for persistence. At work I have recently been introduced to MongoDb, which at least saves me the pain of mapping from database entities to domain entities. These entities all need some ID, and I chose to use an ObjectId from Mongo. Ooops, there comes the deja vu, in order not to have my domain entities being dependent on Mongo, I will once more have to create database and domain entities....as well as the mapping. Bah & Ugh.

In C# I'm used to do such mapping with tools like Automapper, but they don't really work for special F# types. So now I'm wondering what Mark Seeman ment by "using objects for persistance". How is this solved in F#? So far I haven't been able to fine more info on this topic besides the aforementioned question on SO.

Comment: You should consider moving the last paragraph to the top and then adding `TL;DR` before the other paragraphs. By the time I reached the question I realized that only Mark should be answering this and thus I did not need to read all of the other paragraphs.

Comment: @GuyCoder Although Mark knows best what he was talking about in the other SO question, I'm reaching out to the community. You may have a strategy for the mapping issue that I'm facing and I'd also like to hear about your approach.

Comment: what's wrong with serializing?

Comment: @s952163 My "problem" when serializing to Mongo is that I my domain objects are no longer agnostic about serialization, i.e. I have to use either ObjectId or decorate my own ID with [<BsonId>]. In the data access layer, that's OK, but my business layer should not be tied to the storage mechanism. On the other hand, maybe I'm too focused on one thing. Do you have an example showing how you would do it?

Comment: As I read it, you are trying to learn F#, but then constrain yourself into a corner by focusing on how to persist the data. Now that you have yourself in the corner, you believe that you cannot get out unless you get past this problem of persisting data. So I have to ask, do you know about  [formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) and [rewriting system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting)? I personally find that thinking along those lines is synergistic with F#. Although I do find other programming languages to be more synergistic.

Comment: You could serialize first then dump it the result into mongo. But maybe I misunderstand the issue. The way i deal with this is I have some table in a db. Then I have some type. And I have a function that can get stuff from the table and write back to it. The function is the mapper. You want this to be autogenerated? Is that the Q?

Comment: Btw I think this is a good question.

Comment: @GuyCoder I had never heard of formal sytem nor rewriting system, so I will certainly have look at those links. Since I'm a novice F#, maybe I should focus on the creating a working application instead of solving all issues that arise from the DDD that I practice at work (using C#).

Comment: @s952163 My question is indeed about how to either autogenerate mapping, or preventing it in the first place. I gave up on my first attempt at this application because the hand-rolled mapping was too painful. Do you know of any autogenerated mapping that works well for F# types?

Comment: I think that is a wise choice. With regards to formal system and rewriting system it will take much more than looking at the links. I know how to use them, but I am not at the level that I can validate a formal system or teach a formal system, but I do know that for me doing so is on the path I need to be much better at using a computer to solve problems. With regards to picking problems to solve with F#; I find that working with problems already solved with a functional language or in functional manner and translating that to F# works best for me.

Comment: I do have to ask: what do you mean by `focus on the creating a working application`. More importantly how? Will you thinks functions or objects? Will you think composition or inheritance? Will you think recursive or procedural? Will you think immutable or mutable? In other words it is how you think about the problem before writing the first line of code that is beneficial to reaching success with writing functional code.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Otherwise I would've said so. RavenDB is a .NET oriented DB but I believe even they had trouble with F#. So **maybe** this is something peculiar to the language itself, so you can write up as lack of tooling and just use C# for this task.

Comment: @GuyCoder I think it's a good way to learn a language to solve a specific problem that one has. F# is really a general purpose language, maybe better suited for some tasks than others. When one paints oneself in a corner it's not always evident if it's a real corner or an imaginary one.

Comment: @s952163 The point I am trying to make in general is that one should not just take a problem already solved using one programming language and translate it to another programming but that one should first understand how problems are solved, e.g. [Polya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It), then how problems are solved with a computer, then look at the problem and solve it in the way the programming language is designed to be used. I see to many questions where this is not understood, much less taught in school.